# After installing Ubuntu on Mac, when I try to connect to my WiFi it doesn’t work

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, network-manager

I’ve just installed **Ubuntu 20.04.2** on my Mac, and then tried to connect to my wifi but it fails.

After trying to connect for a while, it then prompts "*authentication required*" even though I typed the right password.

I’ve tried rebooting and restarting network manager but it still didn’t work.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Which Mac did you install Ubuntu onto? Some of the WiFi cards need some "special attention" to get working correctly.

Comment: @Matigo I used a MacBook Pro

Comment: *More* specificity, please. There have been 40+ MacBook Pros made over the years, and they do not all have the same wireless device. Which model year is it? For example, "Early 2015", "Late 2016", etc. 

Comment: @Matigo Sorry it’s a 2017 model with big sur 11.2.2

Comment: It's also dual boot

Comment: Ah, you have a 1 in 3 chance of WiFi working. Is this a `14,1`, `14,2`, or `14,3` model? WiFi will only work in Linux with `14,1`. The other two machines will need a WiFi dongle attached ...

Comment: @Matigo it's a 14,2

Comment: In that case, I've not found anyone on the Internet who has gotten that one to work reliably. A WiFi dongle is the easiest and least frustration solution 

Comment: @Matigo guess im getting a wifi dongle, anyways thanks for your help!